# I get error 503 while claiming 0.2 Goerli ETH on Alchemy

Tags: erc-20, ether, testnets, error, goerli

I'm trying to get `0.2 Goerli ETH` in the testnet token faucet, but when I paste my address to claim and I request the amount, I still get the following error:

> '**Request failed with status code 503**'

How to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it was helpful ;) @Mat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes **'error 503'** appear when the server is overloaded for example.

This could be due to they reached the **memory capacity** or often activated by an unusually high number of visitors trying to access at the same time, I couldn't tell you exactly.

It is a common issue while claiming, there are times when I get a `503 error`.

[image]

But if you wait a little to refresh the browser, **you will be able to claim**.

[image]

So try again after some time, for sure it should work.

Check other available [**testnets**](https://bitszn.com/faucets.html) for a while ;)